# Returning a generator inside of a generator

Tags: python, generator

I have a list of integers and and a list of tuples (representing intervals), I want to write a method that, for each tuple, returns the sublists of integers contained in the interval but I want to do it with generators.

For the following input:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
intervals = [(1, 2), (2, 4)]
```

the sublists should be: `[1, 2]` and `[2, 3, 4]`.

My attempt:

```
def gen_intervals(l, intervals):
    for e in l:
        for i in intervals:
            if e > i[0] and e < i[1]:
                yield e
```

However, this would give me a list of elements because the generators yield one element at a time. What I want is to yield *a generator* of the elements in that interval.

Then, I would use it like this:

```
for interval in gen_intervals(l, intervals):
    for e in interval:
        print(e)
```

Important:

- The list is sorted and so are the intervals (even though they may overlap). The intervals follow the standard mathematical representation of an interval: [left endpoint, right endpoint] with left endpoint < right endpoint. For any two intervals u, v, they cannot be a subset of the other. By sorted I mean that their right endpoints are sorted in ascending order.
- I really want to iterate over elements first and intervals later because the list of elements is likely to be very, very long, so I just want to iterate over that list only once. The length of the list of elements is >> the length of the list of the intervals but the exact lengths are arbitrary.

Comment: Please show the desired 'sublists" for your example's tuple. And showing an example with two intervals would be good, showing clearly what you expect. Can there be overlapping intervals? Is the number list sorted?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @KellyBundy. I edited to clarify. Yes, they can be overlapping intervals.

Comment: If they overlap, how do you expect to "*iterate over that list only once'*? If your example had `intervals = [(1,5), (1, 5)]`, wouldn't you iterate it twice?

Comment: no, for each element, you can check if it's in any of the intervals. You don't have to iterate over the list for each interval.

Comment: Ah, so you literally mean iterating over *the list object* only once, and it's ok to iterate over multiple generators which each iterate over the list. You say the intervals are sorted, do you mean each interval, like (2,4) instead of (4,2)? Not that the intervals list is sorted, that's why (2,4) can be before (1,2)? For optimal performance, it would be good to know more about your data: how many numbers, how many intervals, how many numbers are in an interval on average.

Comment: Yes, iterating over the list element once but ideally, the generators use the same iterator over that list (that's what I was hoping at least).

The intervals follow the standard mathematical representation of an interval: [left edge, right edge] with left edge < right edge. By sorted I mean that any two intervals always have a non-empty complement of their intersection and that their right edges are sorted in ascending order. I'm going to clarify, thanks.

Comment: The number of intervals and number of elements in the list is arbitrary... The only constraint is that the length of the list >> length of list of intervals.

Comment: Isn't `[(2, 4), (1, 2)]` invalid then? It's not sorted like it should be. The "non-empty complement of their intersection" sounds odd. Does that for example mean that [(1,4),(1,4)] is valid, since the complement of their intersection is {5} and that's non-empty?

Comment: You're totally right. I corrected the question and updated the description of the intervals.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use a generator comprehension on the `yield` line:

```py
def gen_intervals(elements, intervals):
    for vmin, vmax in intervals:
        yield (elm for elm in elements if (vmin <= elm <= vmax))
```

Which gives:

```py
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
intervals = [(2, 4), (1, 2)]

for interval in gen_intervals(l, intervals):
    for e in interval:
        print(e)
    print()
```

```
2
3
4

1
2
```

Comment: I think this is the most elegant solution so far. My solution is based on this and uses the constraints of the problem to break the generator over the list of elements once an element cannot be in any of the intervals.

Comment: @synack Which "the" generator do you break? That doesn't sound right. What's your solution code?

Comment: @KellyBundy I just posted the solution

Comment: @synack As I suspected, it doesn't match your description. You break the iteration *for each* interval, and you break once the remaining elements cannot be in ***that*** interval. Not once an element cannot be in any of the intervals.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like this. Each interval generator has a buffer, when asked for items it flushes its buffer first and then picks the next list element. If  this element happens to be "its" element, yield it, otherwise place it in the respective interval's buffer and try with the next element.

```
def items_by_iterval(lst, intervals):
    list_iter = iter(lst)
    buffers = [[] for _ in intervals]

    def interval_iter(n):
        while True:
            if buffers[n]:
                yield from buffers[n]
                buffers[n] = []

            try:
                k = next(list_iter)
            except StopIteration:
                return

            for m, (a, b) in enumerate(intervals):
                if a <= k <= b:
                    if m == n:
                        yield k
                    else:
                        buffers[m].append(k)
                    break

    return [interval_iter(n) for n, _ in enumerate(intervals)]


##

lst = [1, 9, 2, 8, 3, 7, 4, 6, 5, 1, 9, 2, 8, 3, 7, 4, 6, 5, ]
intervals = [(5, 7), (2, 4), (8, 10)]

for ii in items_by_iterval(lst, intervals):
    for k in ii:
        print(k, end=' ')
    print()
```

This prints:

```
7 6 5 7 6 5
2 3 4 2 3 4
9 8 9 8
```

Comment: The `break` makes it fail for overlapping intervals.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of any `for` loops you could use `map` to create a list with `True` and `False` values for each element for each interval. Then you could use `itertools.compress` to create an iterator object that yields the elements that are in respective interval:

```py
import itertools

l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
intervals = [(2, 4),]
for interval in intervals:
    # use range(i+1, j) to check if element is in interval
    mapped = map(lambda el: el in range(interval[0] + 1, interval[1]), l)
    # mapped = [False, False, True, False, False]
    res = itertools.compress(l, mapped)  # save this in case of more intervals

print(next(res))  # returns 3
```

Comment: The issue with this solution is that it will iterate over the whole list, even though after a while there may be no other element that falls in any of the intervals. Sorry, I forgot to mention that the list and the intervals are sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @paime's solution:

```
def iterate_interval(l, interval):
    for e in l:
        if e > interval[0]:
            if e < interval[1]:
                yield e
            else: break


def generate_windows(l, intervals):
    for interval in intervals:
        yield iterate_interval(l, interval)
```

This is more efficient because we do not need to continue iterating over the elements once an element is larger than the right endpoint of the interval.

Comment: Fails even you example, doesn't produce [1, 2] and [2, 3, 4] but [] and [3].

Answer (score 0):

Probably faster than yours, as it does two quick binary searches to find the range instead of comparing all elements with the interval bounds. Also, C is faster than Python.

```
from bisect import bisect_left, bisect_right
from itertools import islice

def generate_windows(l, intervals):
    for left, right in intervals:
        yield islice(
            l,
            bisect_left(l, left),
            bisect_right(l, right)
        )

l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
intervals = [(1, 2), (2, 4)]

for window in generate_windows(l, intervals):
    print(*window)
```

Output ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY/PCsIwDMbveYocW@lFnSCCTyJjTJdpoK6jLY49/Wy2ORU8mEv75fvlX9vHm2u2@9YPQ@3dHc8c6BKR763zcVaFpTqal/B8vUUYYY7ko3M2vHgOli8EUFGNV2rIl5GKjpvKdUFZg9ykikdpgz4Apqidx6n52DX5b2QiJHomW8291ZKVsOZLfqwr0@TVP4lxmiDjRy@IBrB4xNPa4Mbg1mBmcJfDspN4SkxtUCUi0zmAHDHdKPv/c3brU0atJkIPwxM)):

```
1 2
2 3 4
```

I have some other ideas that might be even faster, and usually I'd write a benchmark comparing the various solutions, but for that I'd need to know typical sizes, including average number of list elements per interval, and you didn't answer that.